# Rails: will index help for range search?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In my Rails App, I did a alot of range search to group objects, like

```
  scope :best_of_the_week, ->(time) do
    start_time = time.beginning_of_week
    end_time = time.end_of_week
    where("created_at > ? AND created_at < ?", start_time, end_time).where('votes_count > ?', 300).order('votes_count DESC').first(8)
  end
```

In this case, do I need to add index to `created_at`? and what about `votes_count?`

Addtionally, how can I elegantly combine the first two where searches? Or does combining them make any difference?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want max performance to this query, create an index for both.  If you don't want to create too many indexes, you should index created_at, date seems do have a bigger range as the time goes (and size of database).

I like to use the *find_by_sql* and make SELECT retrieve just the essential data to improve performance, if you have too many var chars fields this will have a nice impact.

Just for sintax sugar

```
where("between ? and ?", start_time, end_time).(other stuff)
```

Comment: Is there any difference between `between` and `<` `>`? Which one should I choose?

Comment: I had searched before and could not find a explanation, usually I use between because is more readable, until now I didn't got any problems.